# Post a data onto the web

Tags: http

Watch the transfered content, I found the content of the file is enclosed with some special characters

like 10000

ending with 0 ,

why is there such encodings when uploading files?

Comment: Can you try and make your question a tad clearer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll hazard a guess that you're watching an HTTP transfer that uses the chunked encoding.

In HTTP/1.0, the only way for a sender to indicate the length of the data to be transferred is to supply a Content-Length header. But this requires the sender to know the full length of the content ahead of time, which precludes generating the content on the fly. Chunked transfer encoding avoids this problem by having the sender prefix each chunk of data with a length (e.g. 10000 bytes in your case). The end of the transfer data is indicated by a chunk with zero length.

Knowing the length of the data allows the recipient to detect if the transfer has been truncated, and allows for connection reuse by allowing for an end to a transfer besides the sender closing the connection.

Wikipedia has [an article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) if you want more detail.